# Show integral equality?

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, holomorphic-functions

How to get this equality ?
$$ \forall z\in\mathbb C\backslash\mathbb R_- \;,\ \mathrm{Re}\left\{\int_0^1 \dfrac{z-1}{x(z-1)+1} \,\mathrm dx\right\} = \int_0^1 \dfrac{\vert z\vert -1}{x(\vert z\vert -1) +1}\,\mathrm dx $$
I tried to expand with real and imaginary parts but without success...

Comment: why dont you simply integrate with respect to $x$? $z$ is just a parameter.

Comment: But $z$ is a complex number...

Comment: it doesn't matter as you are only integrating over the real variable $x$. Just integrate both sides with respect to x and then calculate the real part of the right sinde of the expression.